# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.time'

Tags: pygame

today, I was writing a game but I ran into this error.

in this sentence, the error was:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.time'
```

can u guys fix it 4 me? plz?
here is the rest of the 'player' class.

```
class player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__ (self, game):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.game = game
        self.image = pg.Surface((25, 25))
        self.image.fill((255,255,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT/ 2)
        self.pos = vc2(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT/ 2)
        self.vel = vc2(0, 0)
        self.acc = vc2(0, 0)
        
    def update(self):
        self.acc = vc2(0, PL_GRAV)
        ky = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if ky[pg.K_LEFT]:
            self.acc.x = -PL_ACC
        if ky[pg.K_RIGHT]:
            self.acc.x = PL_ACC

        self.acc.x += self.vel.x * PL_FRI
        self.vel += self.acc
        self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc
        if self.pos.x > WIDTH:
            self.pos.x = 0
        if self.pos.x < 0:
            self.pos.x = WIDTH

        self.rect.midbottom = self.pos

    def jump(self):
        self.rect.x += 20
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.plats, False)
        self.rect.x -= 20
        if hits:
            self.vel.y = -15
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the module pygame, but I know python and when you have that type of mistake it's because of the modules. So the only that you need to do it's import the module that you need, this is the page where tell about the module that asking python to continue with your game: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must check what is the current version of pip installed. You can upgrade pip version
Command:
1. Check pip version installed (whether it is pip2 or pip3, sometimes version 2 and 3 conflicts where both python 2 and python3 installed)
   pip -V 
2. Upgrade pip 
   python -m pip install --upgrade pip
3. Then try 
   pip install pygame